# Textured sphere in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to have a *textured* sphere in OpenGl ES. What is the best way to do this? One option is to create it manually. Another is to create it in e.g. Blender and load it - what file format should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In blender, export the model as an obj file. Deselect the 90 degree rotation and select "triangulate". If you are using lighting, enable the normals options.

The next step is to convert the obj file to something easy to use. Use this tool:

http://www.heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/

Now you have your vertices, normals and texture coordinates in arrays ready for you to render.

Good luck!

Edit: Android uses Java right? The tool exports to C header files but you should be able to easily convert it for java.